# How to determine the library list in which Java code is executing when executed in as400 box (rpgle program call)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a Java code which is called from RPGLE and this Java code calls another RPGLE program. during the call or opening any files in Java, It is not recognizing the current user library list.

How can i determine the library list in which the java code is executed?  How can i make it run in library list of current user profile?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using [tag:jt400] library for this?

Comment: How is the Java being called? Are you executing the `RUNJVA` command from within the RPG, or calling a method. Or, are you submitting a new job that eventually executes Java code?

Comment: If the Java is running in the current job, then it will have the same library list as the RPG since the library list is associated with the job, not the program or language. If you are getting a new job, then you need to let us know how that new job is being created, and what the job description and user profile look like.

Comment: Without any code to look at, it's a guess.  Are there any OVRDBFs in effect?  What are the activation groups of the two RPGLE programs?  Is the second RPG program 'not recognizing the library list', or is it the Java program?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: I am calling a method

Comment: How does Java call the second RPG? is it some sort of JNI call or are you connecting to an AS400 object using jt400/jtOpen, and then calling the program that way? Seems like the jtOpen call might be connecting to a prestart job which may have it's own library list. But the initial java call should be running with the same library as the first RPG program.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the different parts of the library list via the AS400 class of the JTOpen project.

```
Job job = as400.getJobs(AS400.COMMAND)[0];
String[] systemLibraryList = job.getSystemLibraryList();
String currentLibrary = job.getCurrentLibrary();
String[] userLibraryList = job.getUserLibraryList();
```

Comment: Interesting. Would this be the Java job running the code in question, or a prestarted server Q* job the as400 object is connected to?

Comment: You are correct. This returns the library list for the prestarted Job even when executed on the IBM i server.

But as the owner of this question also wants to know the library list where a call to another RPG program is executed then using the AS400.getJobs() API is correct as the CommandCall uses the prestarted server jobs.

Comment: This does not make sense to me.  The prestarted command call have no notion what so ever of the library list of the invoking RPGLE job (which seems to be what OP wants to use)

Comment: "... and this Java code calls another RPGLE program ..."

If he is using the CommandCall class from the toolbox he will be using a prestarted job.

I think it is not really clear at what point the op will want a concrete library set.

And yes, you are right. The prestarted job probably has no knowledge or the job it is used by.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a Java program started on the AS/400 you can derive the library list from the `java.library.path`.  Sample content from a V6R1 32-bit JVM.

```
    // java.library.path=/QSYS.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/QSYS2.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/QHLPSYS.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/QUSRSYS.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/QSHELL.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/OUTQLIB.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/QGPL.LIB:
    // /QSYS.LIB/QTEMP.LIB:
    // /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/32bit/jre/lib/ppc:
    // /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/32bit/jre/lib/ppc/classic
```

Split on colons, only consider those starting with /QSYS.LIB/ and ending with .LIB, extract the library name.

As Java work best with using the jt400.jar, you invoke CHGLIBL on the server job on those libraries not present in the system library list before invoking the target program.

Note:  I did this work 5 years ago.  The new JVM's may behave differently.